# Google charts repeating hAxis

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

Is it possible to use ticks with a month name? All the examples I have seen are using years or a number so not sure if it is possible. Basically the graph is repeating the month names like JAN JAN JAN FEB FEB FEB where I just want it to show JAN FEB

```
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Month', '2012', '2013', '2014'],
        ['JAN', 3991, 3910, 3820],
        ['JAN', 4316, 4335, 4104],
        ['JAN', 4478, 4439, 4284],
        ['JAN', 4518, 4385, 4213],
        ['FEB', 4496, 4422, 4291],
        ['FEB', 4525, 4503, 4311],
        ['FEB', 4486, 4433, 4323],
        ['FEB', 4441, 4449, 4304],
        ['MAR', 4470, 4383, 4296],
        ['MAR', 4453, 4463, 4413],
        ['MAR', 4462, 4499, 4342],
        ['MAR', 4353, 4491, 4278],
        ['MAR', 4435, 3912, 4154],
        // more data....

    ]);


  var options = {
      legend: {
          position: 'bottom'
      },
      hAxis: {
          textStyle: {
              color: 'red',
          }
      },
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
  chart.draw(data, options);

}
```

Comment: it's possible, but you will need to use a date value for the x-axis, rather than a string. string values on the x-axis generate a _discrete_ axis. as such, all values are shown. you can use `showTextEvery` to prevent repeating, if you have the same number of rows each month. in the case above, jan & feb = 4, whereas mar = 5. date values generate a continuous axis, which allow for more options...